# How to tag a key in REDIS so later I can remove all keys that match this tag?

Tags: redis

Today we save data like that:

```
redisClient->set($uniquePageID, $data);
```

and output the data like that:

```
redisClient->get($uniquePageID)
```

But now we need to remove the data base on a userID. So we need something like that:

```
redisClient->set($uniquePageID, $data)->tag($userID);
```

So we can remove all the keys that related to this userID only, for example:

```
redisClient->tagDel($userID);
```

Does REDIS can solve something like that?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to come consider using RediSearch for secondary index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do that. Instead, you need to tag these pages by yourself:

- When setting a page-data pair, also put the page id into a `SET` of the corresponding user.
- When you want to remove all pages of a given user, scan the `SET` of the user to get the page ids of this user, and delete these pages.

When scanning the `SET`, you can use either `SMEMBERS` or `SSCAN` command, depends on the size of the `SET`. If it's a big `SET`, prefer `SSCAN` to avoid block Redis for a long time.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thx!

Answer (score -2):

I used HSET and HDEL to store and delete items like this:

```
$this->client = new Predis\Client(array...);
$this->client->hset($key, $tag, $value);
$this->client->hdel($key, $tags)
```

and if you want to delete every item KEY no matter tag or value you can use del key, it works with any data type including hset

```
$this->client->del($key);
```